# Troubleshooting "connection reset" error on my linux server

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos5

I fervently hope someone here can help me with the problem I am experiencing. I am a programmer, and I have very little understanding of linux sysadmin terminology/concepts. I am attempting to troubleshoot a problem with my website. It is a Facebook app, and whenever I try to connect using Chrome, I get an error stating that the "connection was reset". I have been Googling for four days straight trying to find a solution to this problem, but no joy. A big part of the problem is that I do not understand the terminology being employed, and the output from many of the tools referenced is likewise indecipherable to me.

I am running a VPS with CentOS 5, apache, PHP, and MySQL.

I could spam this post with a ton of information from my iptables, apache, etc but if anyone needs information from my server, please let me know how to get it, and I will post it here.

Thank you for any help you can offer!

Apache access_log:

```
199.195.214.49 - - [10/Sep/2012:07:03:25 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 248 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.56 Safari/535.11"
199.195.214.49 - - [10/Sep/2012:07:03:30 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 248 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.56 Safari/535.11"
199.195.214.49 - - [10/Sep/2012:07:03:44 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 248 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.56 Safari/535.11"
199.195.214.49 - - [10/Sep/2012:07:03:44 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 248 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.56 Safari/535.11"
199.195.214.49 - - [10/Sep/2012:07:03:44 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 248 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.56 Safari/535.11"
199.195.214.49 - - [10/Sep/2012:08:24:49 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 248 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.56 Safari/535.11"
199.195.214.49 - - [10/Sep/2012:08:24:55 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 248 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.56 Safari/535.11"
199.195.214.49 - - [10/Sep/2012:08:24:55 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 248 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.56 Safari/535.11"
199.195.214.49 - - [10/Sep/2012:08:24:57 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 248 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.56 Safari/535.11"
199.195.214.49 - - [10/Sep/2012:08:24:57 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 248 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.56 Safari/535.11"
199.195.214.49 - - [10/Sep/2012:08:24:57 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 248 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.56 Safari/535.11"
64.251.28.71 - - [10/Sep/2012:12:01:55 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 248 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.56 Safari/535.11"
64.251.28.71 - - [10/Sep/2012:12:01:57 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 248 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.56 Safari/535.11"
64.251.28.71 - - [10/Sep/2012:12:01:48 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 248 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.56 Safari/535.11"
64.251.28.71 - - [10/Sep/2012:12:01:59 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 248 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.56 Safari/535.11"
64.251.28.71 - - [10/Sep/2012:12:02:00 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 248 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.56 Safari/535.11"
64.251.28.71 - - [10/Sep/2012:12:02:01 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 248 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.56 Safari/535.11"
76.251.107.143 - - [10/Sep/2012:12:18:07 -0600] "POST /?fb_source=bookmark_apps&ref=bookmarks&count=0&fb_bmpos=2_0 HTTP/1.1" 200 5088 "http://apps.facebook.com/railsmp/?fb_source=bookmark_apps&ref=bookmarks&count=0&fb_bmpos=2_0" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.89 Safari/537.1"
76.251.107.143 - - [10/Sep/2012:12:18:25 -0600] "GET /style/bgdesert.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2391 "http://railsmp.us/?fb_source=bookmark_apps&ref=bookmarks&count=0&fb_bmpos=2_0" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.89 Safari/537.1"
76.251.107.143 - - [10/Sep/2012:12:18:30 -0600] "POST /index/difficulty-level?user_id=100000818220013 HTTP/1.1" 200 4155 "http://apps.facebook.com/railsmp/index/difficulty-level?user_id=100000818220013" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.89 Safari/537.1"
76.251.107.143 - - [10/Sep/2012:12:18:35 -0600] "POST /index/new-game HTTP/1.1" 302 - "http://railsmp.us/index/difficulty-level?user_id=100000818220013" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.89 Safari/537.1"
76.251.107.143 - - [10/Sep/2012:12:18:36 -0600] "GET /turn/start-select-city HTTP/1.1" 200 58315 "http://railsmp.us/index/difficulty-level?user_id=100000818220013" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.89 Safari/537.1"
```

Apache error_log:

```
[Tue Sep 04 14:31:35 2012] [error] [client 76.251.107.143] CSRF state token does not match one provided., referer: http://railsmp.us/turn/start-select-city
[Tue Sep 04 14:32:20 2012] [error] [client 76.251.107.143] CSRF state token does not match one provided., referer: http://railsmp.us/turn/start-select-city
[Tue Sep 04 14:32:30 2012] [error] [client 76.251.107.143] CSRF state token does not match one provided., referer: http://railsmp.us/turn/start-select-city
[Tue Sep 04 14:36:59 2012] [error] [client 76.251.107.143] CSRF state token does not match one provided., referer: http://railsmp.us/turn/start-select-city
[Tue Sep 04 14:39:13 2012] [error] [client 76.251.107.143] CSRF state token does not match one provided., referer: http://railsmp.us/turn/start-select-city
[Tue Sep 04 14:39:44 2012] [error] [client 76.251.107.143] CSRF state token does not match one provided., referer: http://railsmp.us/turn/start-select-city
[Tue Sep 04 14:39:51 2012] [error] [client 76.251.107.143] CSRF state token does not match one provided., referer: http://railsmp.us/turn/start-select-city
[Tue Sep 04 14:39:58 2012] [error] [client 76.251.107.143] CSRF state token does not match one provided., referer: http://railsmp.us/turn/start-select-city
[Tue Sep 04 14:40:06 2012] [error] [client 76.251.107.143] CSRF state token does not match one provided., referer: http://railsmp.us/turn/start-select-city
[Tue Sep 04 16:17:43 2012] [error] [client 76.251.107.143] CSRF state token does not match one provided., referer: http://railsmp.us/turn/start-select-city
[Tue Sep 04 16:23:35 2012] [error] [client 76.251.107.143] CSRF state token does not match one provided., referer: http://railsmp.us/turn/start-select-city
[Tue Sep 04 23:14:57 2012] [error] [client 76.251.107.143] CSRF state token does not match one provided., referer: http://railsmp.us/turn/start-select-city
[Tue Sep 04 23:15:05 2012] [error] [client 76.251.107.143] CSRF state token does not match one provided., referer: http://railsmp.us/turn/start-select-city
[Tue Sep 04 23:15:12 2012] [error] [client 76.251.107.143] CSRF state token does not match one provided., referer: http://railsmp.us/turn/start-select-city
[Tue Sep 04 23:15:25 2012] [error] [client 76.251.107.143] CSRF state token does not match one provided., referer: http://railsmp.us/turn/start-select-city
[Tue Sep 04 23:24:47 2012] [error] [client 76.251.107.143] CSRF state token does not match one provided., referer: http://railsmp.us/turn/start-select-city
[Wed Sep 05 17:09:04 2012] [error] [client 208.127.18.112] CSRF state token does not match one provided., referer: http://railsmp.us/turn/start-select-city
[Wed Sep 05 17:09:13 2012] [error] [client 208.127.18.112] CSRF state token does not match one provided., referer: http://railsmp.us/turn/start-select-city
[Wed Sep 05 17:09:25 2012] [error] [client 208.127.18.112] CSRF state token does not match one provided., referer: http://railsmp.us/turn/start-select-city
[Wed Sep 05 17:17:57 2012] [error] [client 208.127.18.112] CSRF state token does not match one provided., referer: http://railsmp.us/turn/start-select-city
[Thu Sep 06 00:11:49 2012] [error] [client 76.251.107.143] CSRF state token does not match one provided., referer: http://railsmp.us/turn/start-select-city
[Thu Sep 06 00:12:44 2012] [error] [client 76.251.107.143] CSRF state token does not match one provided., referer: http://railsmp.us/turn/start-select-city
```

Comment: The first place to look is your Apache logs.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like the tokens you are using/implemented to prevent Cross Site Request Forgery are not validating. It could be your connection gets reset as a preventive measure to prevent attackers from doing illegal requests.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah, that's an old error that I've already resolved. There aren't any new errors for the problem that I'm encountering.

Comment: If there is no meaningful logs regarding this issue, you'll need to expand the tools you're using. Maybe a network trace or a stack trace on the Chrome process handling the app?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a 'network trace' or 'stack trace.' I googled those terms, and it seems to refer to a tcpdump, which I did, but the output it captured appeared to be garbage when I viewed it in a text editor. Can you please clarify what command/process I should use? Thanks.

Comment: I'm really sorry that I'm such a NOOB, but if anyone could please help me out, I would really appreciate it!